# htaccess - forcing non-www to www across entire site

Tags: apache, .htaccess

With:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.org
 RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mysite.org/$1 [R=301,L]
```

its redirecting http://mysite.org to http://www.mysite.org just fine

........ however if anything is trailing, its not forcing the www.

IE

http://mysite.org/b/ is NOT redirecting to http://www.mysite.org/b/

Comment: ah-ha! that was it. So simple. Thanks! How can I give credit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure there is only one `.htaccess` and that the folder `b` doesn't have a inner `.htaccess` or any other folder that is not redirecting. Besides that your rule should work just fine.